# Shouldn't istream::peek() always return what you just putback()?

Tags: c++, istream, libc++

Intuitively, judging from the C++ spec, it looks to me as if `istream::putback( c )` should always arrange the input buffer such that the next call to `istream::peek()` should read the character `c`. Is this not correct? I ask because the latest version of libc++ shipping with Xcode 4.6 seems not to enforce this behavior in all cases—particularly when the last character is at the EOF. The same is true if you use `unget()` instead of `putback( c )`.

Is libc++'s behavior correct, or is my intuition of how `putback()/unget()` should work correct?

Consider this example code, which works with libstdc++ but not with libc++ (the assertion fails).

```
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::istringstream in( "[Test]" );

    while( in )
    {
        int c = in.get();
        if( c == ']' )
        {
            in.putback( c );
            assert( in.peek() == c );   // Fails with libc++. Succeeds with libstdc++.
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are any of `eofbit`, `failbit`, `badbit` set after the `putback(c)`? (For reference: With libstdc++ 4.7, none of those are set, the stream is `good()`.)

Comment: +1 to both of the answers.  Looks like a bug in libc++ that was fixed in r162608.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There has actually been a change to the `putback` function in C++11:

§27.7.2.3/34

> `basic_istream<charT,traits>& putback(char_type c);`
>
> Effects: Behaves as an unformatted input function (as described in 27.7.2.3, paragraph 1), except that the function first clears `eofbit`. ...

Where the second half of the sentence didn't exist in C++03.

So it might depend on whether the compilers have fully implemented this change, or  if you use the required options (`-std=C++11`?).

Answer (score 4):

Bo Persson is correct about the standards. You are probably using an older version of libc++ (your problem is in the LLVM bugtracker, see below).

The change was introduced in revision 162108:

```
--- istream     (revision 162607)
+++ istream     (revision 162608)
@@ -1263,6 +1263,7 @@
     try
     {
 #endif  // _LIBCPP_NO_EXCEPTIONS
+        this->clear(this->rdstate() & ~ios_base::eofbit);
         sentry __sen(*this, true);
         if (__sen)
         {
```

The log concerning the change:

> $ svn log -r 162608
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ r162608 | hhinnant | 2012-08-25 00:03:03 +0200 (Sat, 25 Aug 2012) | 1
> line
>
> Have basic_istream seekg, putback and unget first clear eofbit.  Fixes
> http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13089.